# GNOME Screensaver Widgets

Tags: linux, gnome, screensaver

Is there a way to add widgets to a Gnome screensaver? I think [this can be done with KDE 4](https://superuser.com/questions/120503/use-a-web-page-as-screensaver-linux), but I've never liked KDE very much. I'm a programmer and comfortable with writing code if needed.

I'd like to be able to:

1. See the weather and forecast
2. Control Rhythmbox
3. Use a flash card widget for reviewing musical concepts

The reason I want these on the screensaver is that I have login restrictions. I would like to be able to do a very limited subset of activities without having to log in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the Gnome screen saver is a (heavily?) modified version of [XScreenSaver](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/) by jwz. He won't support the Gnome version, but [his source code](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/faq.html#writing-savers) (and theirs) may provide you some pointers to get started.

- [Gnome Screensaver FAQs](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeScreensaver/FrequentlyAskedQuestions)
- [Gnome Screensaver Source Browser](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-screensaver/tree/src)

Comment: Thanks for the note. In the FAQ I found this: "gnome-screensaver runs the screen lock password dialog in a separate process and embeds the interface using XEmbed." This means I can replace that dialog program if I wish. This sounds like the best place to hook in.